# Keyerror in Python when retrieving json data

Tags: python, json

I created a Python script to fetch open orders from a cryptocurrency exchange.

When i connect to the api using:

```
order = exchange.fetch_open_orders(symbol)
```

I receive this response:

```
[{'info': {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 
            'orderId': 507325551, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 
            'web_b75c7f9be90849beac14cd86f575ac01', 'price': '0.02504200', 
            'origQty': '0.02100000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 
            'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'NEW', 
            'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'SELL', 
            'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 
            'time': 1571163346981, 'updateTime': 1571163346981, 'isWorking': True}, 
            'id': '507325551', 'timestamp': 1571163346981, 'datetime': '2019-10-15T18:15:46.981Z', 
            'lastTradeTimestamp': None, 
            'symbol': 'ETH/BTC', 'type': 'limit', 
            'side': 'sell', 'price': 0.025042, 
            'amount': 0.021, 'cost': 0.0, 'average': None, 'filled': 0.0, 
            'remaining': 0.021, 'status': 'open', 'fee': None, 'trades': None}]
```

Which is a very long response and i don't want everything here, To print only some values i tried this:

```
for x in order:
    sym = x['symbol']
    price = x['price']
    status = x['status']
    amount = x['amount']
    side = x['side']
    orig = x['origQty']


print(sym, price, status, amount, side, orig)
```

This code works until the line `orig = x['origQty']` where i get a `KeyError: 'origQty'`.

I don't understand where is this coming from since all the other variables are printed without any error and because `origQty` **is** in the response, whereas this error usually appears when i try to look for something that doesn't exist.
Can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The origQty key exists only in the inner dict. You are only getting items from the outer dict. Use `x["info"] ["origQty"] ` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that your dict has an inner dict which contains `origQty`

so 
`orig = x['info']['origQty']`

## Update

check [this](https://jsonblob.com/3dbd5393-ef84-11e9-8274-ad53e060e248), i think it will make it more clear in visualaizing it :)

Comment: It's working! But why don't i have to do this for all the other values? Give me 6 minutes to accept your answer

Comment: Because those keys are also present outside of `info`

Comment: @Jack022 i added a link, go check it, it display the json visual, which help you to understand it

Comment: Checking it out. Thanks again @Reznik!

Answer (score 1):

`'origQty'` is nested under the `'info'` key, try using `x['info']['origQty']` instead.